# Accessing a Combobox inside a dataGridView Column?

Tags: c++, datagridview, visual-c++-2010, datagridviewcombobox

I'm working on a scheduling program, and inside the dataGridView, we have a few ComboBox Columns that are populated by 3 entries upon creation, but I wanted to be able to add more as the user creates them, but I have no idea how you would access the combobox data. Any help is appreciated!

```
// this is initialized in a separate part.
/* System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView^ dataGridView;*/

System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewComboBoxColumn^ newCol = 
    (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewComboBoxColumn());

dataGridView->Columns->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewComboBoxColumn^  >(1) {newCol});  

// add the choices to the boxes.
newCol->Items->AddRange("User inputted stuff", "More stuff", "Add New...");
```

Comment: I'm puzzled. It's not the **user**, that creates entries. It's **your application** that does, on behalf of the user. I have no clue, how you can have implemented the functionality, and now ask for help with implementing the very same functionality. What am I missing?

Comment: Inside the columns, there are the drop-down comboboxes, and when the user selects "Add New", they're presented with a textbox that requests a new input. When it's inputted, however, I don't know how to add that into the combobox for them to select in the future.

Comment: Show how you add items in the `ComboBoxColumn` in the begining

Comment: @Fabio I added the requested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

If you have access to the data from the user entry and you know the column index for the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, you should be able to just do the following wherever needed:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn^ comboboxColumn = dataGridView->Columns[the_combobox_column_index];

if (comboboxColumn != nullptr)
{
    comboboxColumn->Items->Add("the new user entry");
}
```

---

**Comments Response**

> how could you change the selected index of that combobox (the one that
>   the edit was triggered on)? [...] we want it so that when the new item
>   is added the selected index is set to that new item).

Couple of ways come to mind.

1. Add a single line within the `if-statement` of the above code.  This will set the default displayed value for each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` in the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

   ```
   if (comboboxColumn != nullptr)
   {
       comboboxColumn->Items->Add("the new user entry");
       comboboxColumn->DefaultCellStyle->NullValue = "the new user entry";
   }
   ```

   - Pros: Clean, efficient. Previous user-selected values are *left intact*.  The cell's `FormattedValue` will display the new user value by default if no other selection has been made.
   - Cons: Doesn't *actually* set a cell's selected value, so `Value` will return `null` on cells not explicitly user-selected.
2. Actually *set* the value of certain cells (based on your criteria) to the user-added value.

   ```
   if (comboboxColumn != nullptr)
   {
       comboboxColumn->Items->Add("the new user entry");

       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView->Rows->Count; i++)
       {
           DataGridViewComboBoxCell^ cell = dataGridView->Rows[i]->Cells[the_combobox_column_index];

           if ( cell != nullptr /* and your conditions are met */ )
           {
               cell->Value = "the new user entry";
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   - Pros: The `Value` of targeted cells is *actually* set to the new user value.
   - Cons: Logic deciding *which* cells should be affected is more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first off. Now, given that `comboboxColumn` how could you change the selected index of that combobox (the one that the edit was triggered on)? (I know this isn't really part of the question but i'm working on the project with Ralis and we want it so that when the new item is added the selected index is set to that new item)

Comment: @StephenB Edited my answer to address your additional questions. Hope that helps.  Let me know if I misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Thank you very much I think that is exactly what we needed. I'll make sure Ralis accepts this answer when I see him Monday. Thanks again!